# Increase DPI of plt.show()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using Matplotlib in a Jupyter Notebook to display an image of a map. The code looks like this:

```
%matplotlib inline

imgpath = './map.png'

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

from PIL import Image

img = Image.open(imgpath)
print(img.size)

width, height = img.size
# img.thumbnail((width * 2,height * 2), Image.ANTIALIAS)  # resizes image in-place
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
plt.savefig('test.png', dpi = 300)
```

The problem is, although the `plt.savefig('test.png', dpi = 300)` looks fine (because I changed the dpi to 300), the image displayed in the notebook is so low resolution I can't make anything out on it, and `plt.imshow(img, dpi = 300)` doesn't work:

[image: Image displayed in notebook]

So what I'm wondering is if there is a way to change the resolution of the image shown in the Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Have you tried right click => open image ? It'll open it and you'll have more details.

Comment: Thanks, that does make it a little better, but still smaller/lower resolution than ideal.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Add this at the beginning of the notebook:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 300
```

That's it !

Comment: For the modern displays, I suggest using 600 DPI. Otherwise it could look pixellated on your phone or tablet.

Comment: Also work with `matplotlib.pyplot`. That is, `plt.rcParams[...]`

Comment: @IvanGonzalez `plt.rcParams['figure.dpi']=300` just doesn't work!

Answer (score 40):

If your screen has Retina display, add the following line after `%matplotlib inline` (or somewhere else before plotting) in your notebook

```
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'
```

This will increase the display resolution of your plots *within the* Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Hmm, Retina Display as in a Mac? Unfortunately I'm doing this on a PC and adding that line doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Even some Windows laptops have Retina display. But if doesn't help you then your screen doesn't have one. You can try providing a bigger figure size to have a magnified image

Comment: @Sheldore Do you have any suggestion for Spyder? This command did not yield any changes in my MacOS.

Answer (score 26):

Using the solution proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51955985/738017) has the drawbacks to apply the DPI to all the other figures that will be created within the notebook.

This is fine in most cases, but if you need to set the DPI value ONLY for one figure, you can do it as follows:

```
plt.imshow(img)
plt.gcf().set_dpi(300)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You can also create a figure with a given dpi via `fig = plt.figure(dpi=100)`