# How can I make numbers clear both on x- and y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot an image but I found both values in x- and y-axis are not clear and a bit blurred, here is my code

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.unicode'] = True

bar_cycle = (cycler('hatch', ['///', '--', '...','\///', 'xxx', '\\\\'])*
             cycler('color', 'w')*cycler('zorder', [10]))
styles = bar_cycle()

values = [250, 600, 1000]
ind = np.arange(1, 4)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
for i in range(1, 4):
    ax.bar(i, values[i-1], width=0.35, edgecolor='black', **next(styles))

ax.set_xticks(ind)
ax.set_xticklabels([r'A', r'B', r'C'])
ax.set_ylim([0, 1200])
ax.set_ylabel('episodes')

fig.savefig('figure.pdf')
```

How can I improve that and make values with bold fonts?

[image]

Comment: What happens if you change the format of figure you saved, like png?

Comment: @hemanta just the same result. `png` is not a good format for academic-purpose papers.

Comment: I see, my another thought is, Print ( plt.style.available) so you will have many available styles.  'seaborn-paper' might works.

Comment: @GoingMyWay: Are you by any chance using a Macbook or a retina display enabled system? Also, did you try `fig.savefig('figure.pdf', dpi=1000)` let's say

Comment: @Bazingaa hi thank you. I use Macbook with retina display.

Comment: @GoingMyWay: Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51937381/increase-dpi-of-matplotlib-show-in-jupyter-notebook/51937431#51937431)

Comment: @GoingMyWay: Then I would like to mark it as a duplicate